# Novel about a woman that could follow strings of flux to travel

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a sci-fi novel in early 80’s about a woman on a planet that could follow strings of flux to get from one place to another.

She was part of a train of slaves being transferred to another location when she found she could see the strings and use them to free herself.

I have looked at all kinds of stores and done multiple searches online for this but to no avail.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63550/i-am-looking-for-an-older-series-about-space-colonization

Answer (score 6):

This is almost certainly the [Soul Rider](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/584402.Spirits_of_Flux_and_Anchor) series by Jack L Chalker.

[image]

In the first book Spirits of Flux and Anchor, the heroine Cassie is possessed by a Soul Rider and when that is discovered she is sold into slavery by the matriarchy that ruled her Anchor.  Once out in the wild (the Flux) that exists between Anchors, she discovers that she can see the flux in the same way as the slave master leading them.

The books were first published in 1984, so that fits your timeframe and the link from [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Spirits-Flux-Anchor-Soul-Rider/dp/0812533208) should give you a taste of the first book and will be the culmination of your search.

Comment: See this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189522/book-series-describing-the-evolution-of-religious-practices-christian-muslim-t/189559#189559)

Comment: Cheri, of this is the answer to your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark by the voting buttons.